# Check if a date is valid with in a given period

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table named “**Members**”

With a column named “**AffiliationDate** (datetime, null)”  2016-04-30 00:00:00.000

A affiliation **period** runs from (example):
2016 – 07 – 01  to  2017 – 06 – 30

Now I want to see if a Member **AffiliationDate** is valid for this **period**

I have tried to do this without success, hoping for some tips directions.

Thanks in advance,
Rick

Comment: Look up `BETWEEN`.

Comment: You can use `AffiliationDate BETWEEN ... AND ...` or the equivalent `AffiliationDate >= AND AffiliationDate <= ...`

Comment: If you are (sometimes) storing time values as well as dates, you may want to use half-closed intervals to represent periods. E.g. if your period is intended to cover all of July 2016 through to all of June 2017, represent the end-date as `2017-07-01` and use `<` rather than `<=` in your comparisons. This tends to be easier to work with and you won't accidentally exclude a member with an `AffiliationDate` of `2017-06-30T15:45:27`. Just an aside really. (If you don't work with times, may be worth considering switching the data type to `date`)

Answer (score 0):

Use a **[`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)** expression to check whether the `AffiliationDate` is **[`BETWEEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187922.aspx)** the range of dates.

**Query**

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN [AffiliationDate] BETWEEN '2016–07–01' AND '2016–07–30'
THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid' END AS [Status]
FROM [Members];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = (Define your start date)
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME   = (Define your end date)

SELECT * 
FROM Members 
WHERE AffiliationDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Basically, you don't need to declare those two variables.  The way I used here should make the query clear.  The method Damien_The_Unbeliever mentioned should work for you.  Also, you can use `DATEADD()` function to manupliate your start and end dates (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx for detail).  Hope this helps.